# Rebuild project in Intellij IDEA each time before run

Tags: intellij-idea

In case of my project I need to rebuild whole project before run any test. Is it possible to turn on rebuilding each time before run. IDEA uses Make each time but it's just rebuild modified files.

Comment: Something about this workflow feels...off.  Notwithstanding that every time something's run, the default Make task is run, why do you need to rebuild your entire project when writing/running a single unit test?

Comment: Create Ant script with one target to delete project "out", then add a step to call that Ant script prior to "Make" in the configuration. Can you elaborate on why do you need full rebuild?

Comment: @kukido Could you please share this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @AndreyMyatlyk his answer helped to me

> Create Ant script with one target to delete project "out", then add a
>   step to call that Ant script prior to "Make" in the configuration. Can
>   you elaborate on why do you need full rebuild? –  @Andrey Myatlyuk

Answer (score 0):

same problem. if change res need rebuild every time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).