# How to make IntelliJ to clean output artifact directory before deploy?

Tags: intellij-idea

In `Run/Debug configuration` there is no option to select `clean` in section `Before launch`. How to make run configuration so IntelliJ 12 would clean output directory before deploying there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the menubar select `Build -> BuildArtifacts -> All Artifacts -> Clean`

[image: IntelliJ IDEA how to clean artifacts]

Answer (score 2):

First, open `File | Settings | Compiler` then ensure that `Clear output directory on rebuild` is enabled. Then hit `Alt+B,r` to rebuild your project.

edit: If you *really* want to rebuild before each launch, you can create a custom ant script and invoke it before launch, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773662/rebuild-project-in-intellij-idea-each-time-before-run).

Comment: `Project Settings` windows does not have any `Clear output directory on rebuild` and `Compiler` field in IntelliJ 12

Comment: The Settings window gets rearranged often.  The checkbox is still there, but in `Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler` (at least in current version, Community 2021.1).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer by @reviteja. I also found following solution to this problem

> In the corresponding run/debug configuration, add the Build
>    artifact task to the Before launch task list. The
>   artifact will be built automatically when you execute the run/debug
>   configuration (Run | Run or Run | Debug).

from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html)